# Binding doesn't work for navigation properties

Tags: wpf, lazy-loading, datacontext, binding

I am binding WPF with Entity-Framework.

The Window.DataContext property is set to a Quote.
This Quote has a property Job, that I have to trigger `Quote.JobReference.Load` it should load from the server.

```
<ContentControl Content="{Binding Job}" 
    ContentTemplate="{StaticResource JobTemplateSummary}"/>
```

As you can see above, I am trying to bind a `ContentControl` to the Window's `DataContext` which is a `StaticResource` `Quote` class.

I am calling the Load in the `Window.Load` even handler.
Should I've called somewhere else?

Comment: Why do you ask yourself that question ? Because it doesn't work, or because you want a better solution ?

Comment: Because it doesn't work.
So when I found the solution, I think it would be fair share it with the community instead of deleting the entire thread; so people can enjoy in future when they encounter a similar issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that Navigation Properties don't call `PropertyChanged` event by default so when the window is bound (which is before Page_Load handler) the JobReference was still not Loaded, we have to call `Quote.OnPropertyChanged("Job")` explicitly when the job property changes, so the WPF UI knows to refresh the control binding.

I added the following to the `Quote` class, and this solved the problem:

```
Public Sub New()
    AddHandler JobReference.AssociationChanged, _
        AddressOf Job_AssociationChanged
End Sub

Sub Job_AssociationChanged(sender As Object, e As CollectionChangeEventArgs)
    OnPropertyChanged("Job")
End Sub
```